# Zero test executed by Karma (AngularJS, RequireJS)

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have an AngularJS 1.5.11 app where RequireJS 2.2.0 is used everywhere. Unit tests are needed. And I can't get even a dummy test executed. Please advise.

The error:

`PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.044 secs / 0 secs)`

Detailed debug level output from `karma start --browsers PhantomJS_custom --log-level debug` command: https://gist.github.com/sergibondarenko/1120d211aa2265b76669cd831495a6c1

Test: 
*app/controllers/__tests__/loginController.spec.js*

```
define('loginController', [], function () {
  describe('loginController', function () {
    it('dymmy test', function () {
      expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
  });
});
```

Karma config: https://gist.github.com/sergibondarenko/4b305341faa24883cb90e6f8f7490d74

Test-main: https://gist.github.com/sergibondarenko/6aa25bf71bfadf39883a59d7cda57a65

Dev dependencies:

```
:~/dev/qxip/hepic$ grep -rn devD package.json -A 9
20:  "devDependencies": {
21-    "jasmine": "^2.8.0",
22-    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
23-    "karma": "^0.13.22",
24-    "karma-browserify": "^5.1.1",
25-    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
26-    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
27-    "protractor": "^4.0.9",
28-    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
29-  },
```

The app structure is below. Some libs are in `node_modules`, other libs are in `lib` folder.

```
user@host:~/dev$ tree -L 1 theapp
theapp
├── app
├── css
├── font-awesome
├── fonts
├── img
├── index.html
├── karma.conf.js
├── lang
├── lib
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── resources
├── scripts
├── share
├── templates
├── test-main.js
├── tests
└── widgets
```

Please tell me if you need more info.

Comment: where are you running your tests from ? Also, can you list the complete path for test-main.js instead of just the filename in karma.conf.js ?

Comment: @82Tuskers I run command `karma start --browsers PhantomJS_custom --log-level debug` from my app root folder - `~/dev/theapp`. The complete path for the test-main.js is `~/dev/theapp/test-main.js`, please look the app structure above.

Comment: can you add a folder beneath app called test; that is `/app/test/` and then add your test file as `test-file.spec.js`. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `karma.conf.js` set this:

```
browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'PhantomJS_custom'],

    // you can define custom flags
    customLaunchers: {
      'PhantomJS_custom': {
        base: 'PhantomJS',
        options: {
          windowName: 'my-window',
          settings: {
            webSecurityEnabled: false
          },
        },
        flags: ['--load-images=true'],
        debug: true
      }
    },

    phantomjsLauncher: {
      // Have phantomjs exit if a ResourceError is encountered (useful if karma exits without killing phantom)
      exitOnResourceError: true
    }
```

Then supposing that you have your `karma.conf.js` file in the root, the same level where your `app` subfolder is and your `test-main.js` is, execute your tests through:

```
karma start karma.conf.js
```

Comment: but I have this part already, look the second gist above https://gist.github.com/sergibondarenko/4b305341faa24883cb90e6f8f7490d74#file-karma-conf-js-L60

Comment: so what about your files structure? is it as explained?

Comment: have you tried to execute your tests through `karma start karma.conf.js` so?

Comment: Yes, I did, the same error - `PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.045 secs / 0 secs)`

Comment: You have an issue in your `test-main.js`. In order to prove that, please remove your dynamic code, and at the moment just push a static test file to your array please: `allTestFiles.push(HEREMYSTATICTESTFILE);` and check if the static file gets executed. Get back to me once tried please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152963/discussion-between-trex-and-quirimmo).